# C Header files not working?

Tags: c, file, header, undefined-reference

I can't get my runner.c to see my mergesort.h import, just the last thing I need to do before I go through and add in comments.

Not seeing what I am doing wrong here so I thought I'd get more eyes to look at it. I looked up questions on here and also pretty much copied the template my lab professor has but it still won't work.

**Error**

```
/tmp/ccf8TT1E.o: In function `main':
/home/carson/CProgs/lab5/runner.c:10: undefined reference to `mergeSort'
/home/carson/CProgs/lab5/runner.c:11: undefined reference to `print'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**runner.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mergesort.h"

int main()
{
    int length = 4;
    int array[4] = {7,5,3,1};

    mergeSort(array, length);
    print(array,length);
}
```

**mergesort.h**

```
#ifndef MERGESORT_H_
#define MERGESORT_H_

void mergeSort(int* x, int length);

#endif
```

**mergesort.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mergesort.h"

void mergeSort(int* array, int length)
{
    if(length == 2)
    {
        if(array[1] < array[0])
        {
            swap(&array[1],&array[0]);
        }
        return;
    }
    else if(length == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(length%2 == 0)
        {

            int halfLength = length/2;
            int bottomHalf[halfLength];
            int topHalf[halfLength];

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i <= (halfLength); i++)
            {
                bottomHalf[i] = array[i];
                topHalf[i] = array[i+(halfLength)];
            }

            mergeSort(bottomHalf, halfLength);
            mergeSort(topHalf, halfLength);

            int arrayLoc = 0;
            int bottomHalfLoc = 0;
            int topHalfLoc = 0;
            while(bottomHalfLoc < halfLength && topHalfLoc < halfLength)
            {
                if(bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc] > topHalf[topHalfLoc])
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = topHalf[topHalfLoc];
                    topHalfLoc++;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc];
                    bottomHalfLoc++;
                }

                arrayLoc++;
            }

            if(bottomHalfLoc < arrayLoc)
            {
                while(bottomHalfLoc < halfLength)
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc];
                    bottomHalfLoc++;
                    arrayLoc++;
                }
            }

            return;
        }else 
        {
            int halfLength = length/2;
            int bottomHalf[halfLength];
            int topHalf[halfLength+1];

            int i;
            for(i = 0; i <= (halfLength); i++)
            {
                bottomHalf[i] = array[i];
            }

            for(i = 0; i <=(halfLength+1); i++)
            {
                topHalf[i] = array[i+halfLength];
            }

            mergeSort(bottomHalf, halfLength);
            mergeSort(topHalf, halfLength);

            int arrayLoc = 0;
            int bottomHalfLoc = 0;
            int topHalfLoc = 0;
            while(bottomHalfLoc < halfLength && topHalfLoc < halfLength)
            {
                if(bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc] > topHalf[topHalfLoc])
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = topHalf[topHalfLoc];
                    topHalfLoc++;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc];
                    bottomHalfLoc++;
                }

                arrayLoc++;
            }

            if(bottomHalfLoc < arrayLoc)
            {
                while(bottomHalfLoc < halfLength)
                {
                    array[arrayLoc] = bottomHalf[bottomHalfLoc];
                    bottomHalfLoc++;
                    arrayLoc++;
                }
            }
        return;
        }
    }
}

void swap(int *smallerValue, int *largerValue)
{
    int temp = *smallerValue;
    *smallerValue = *largerValue;
    *largerValue = temp;
}


void print(int array[], int length)
{
    printf("%d",array[0]); 
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf(",%d",array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the header file, how are you invoking the compiler command?

Comment: You observe a linker error.

Comment: gcc runner.c -o runner.out   ?

Comment: do gcc -c runner.c mergesort.h mergesort.c and then gcc -o myprogram runner.o mergesort.o

Answer (score 0):

use `gcc *.c -o runner.out` and one more thing i dont see print function in mergesort.h file but u r calling it in the main function. include it or use `extern print(array,length);`